# Minimize sum of a column within multiple combinations of other variables

Tags: python, r, tidyverse, combinations

This one has me banging my head against the wall... would love some help.

I will explain an example of what I am trying to do below with simulated data, but essentially I am trying to minimize the sum of a column within multiple combinations of other variables.

---

Question: within each `team` and `trailhead`, what is the fastest way to get all the runners within `complete_team` to finish a race (`total_hours`) by looking at the different combinations of runners in `team_runners_at_departure` and `other_runners_at_departure`?

Each row of the dataset below represents one complete 'running' of a race. The variables are:

- `team_runners_at_departure`: the people running and being timed in this row of data
- `other_runners_at_departure`: non-team members at the departure. imagine that sometimes people run faster/slower against different people.
- `all_runners_at_departure`: equals `team_runners_at_departure` + `other_runners_at_departure`
- `complete_team`: all the members of the team (e.g. including members that might not be running in the scenario). Each of these members to finish the race for it to be complete!
- `team`: just a team name. varies with `complete_team`
- `trailhead`: the name of the race (imagine there could be many different races). This is what we want to know the minimums *within* (e.g. what is the fastest combinations of runners that `team1` can use to finish `trail_one`)?
- `total_hours`: The time is takes `team_components_at_departure` to finish the race

---

Setting up a story: Pretend that I have information regarding how long it takes different combinations of the members of a running group to complete a trail run. So, a team of runners might have two people in it and they can run it individually or together, so that would be three combinations, each taking a different number of hours.

I want to know, for each trail they might run, what the fastest way is for a *team* to complete the run - is it together, separate, etc? So that takes knowing multiple running times (which are rows in my dataset) and minimizing it by group.

However, the tricky thing is that other runners are present too. Pretend they affect the team members differently, so I ultimately want to know across all the possible combinations of: the running team members *and* the combinations of other possible runners, what the fastest way to get each complete team finished is. So again, this takes knowing the times of multiple groups of runners within a team and minimizing the total time by group.

---

Data for `R`:

```
structure(list(team_runners_at_departure = c("adam", "adam", 
"adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam, brittany", 
"adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", 
"adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, mike", 
"adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike", 
"adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"brittany", "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", 
"brittany", "brittany", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", 
"mike", "mike", "mike", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", 
"mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", 
"mike, brittany", "brad", "brad", "brad", "brad", "brad", "brad", 
"brad", "brad", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "hailey", "hailey", "hailey", "hailey", "hailey", 
"hailey", "hailey", "hailey"), other_runners_at_departure = c("fred", 
"fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", "none", 
"fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", 
"none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", 
"none", "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", 
"gina", "none", "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", 
"gina", "gina", "none", "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", 
"fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", "none", "fred", "fred", 
"fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", "none", "amy", 
"amy", "john", "john", "john, amy", "john, amy", "none", "none", 
"amy", "amy", "john", "john", "john, amy", "john, amy", "none", 
"none", "amy", "amy", "john", "john", "john, amy", "john, amy", 
"none", "none"), all_runners_at_departure = c("adam fred", "adam fred", 
"adam fred gina", "adam fred gina", "adam gina", "adam gina", 
"adam", "adam", "adam brittany fred", "adam brittany fred", "adam brittany fred gina", 
"adam brittany fred gina", "adam brittany gina", "adam brittany gina", 
"adam brittany", "adam brittany", "adam mike fred", "adam mike fred", 
"adam mike fred gina", "adam mike fred gina", "adam mike gina", 
"adam mike gina", "adam mike", "adam mike", "adam mike brittany fred", 
"adam mike brittany fred", "adam mike brittany fred gina", "adam mike brittany fred gina", 
"adam mike brittany gina", "adam mike brittany gina", "adam mike brittany", 
"adam mike brittany", "brittany fred", "brittany fred", "brittany fred gina", 
"brittany fred gina", "brittany gina", "brittany gina", "brittany", 
"brittany", "mike fred", "mike fred", "mike fred gina", "mike fred gina", 
"mike gina", "mike gina", "mike", "mike", "mike brittany fred", 
"mike brittany fred", "mike brittany fred gina", "mike brittany fred gina", 
"mike brittany gina", "mike brittany gina", "mike brittany", 
"mike brittany", "brad amy", "brad amy", "brad john", "brad john", 
"brad john amy", "brad john amy", "brad", "brad", "brad hailey amy", 
"brad hailey amy", "brad hailey john", "brad hailey john", "brad hailey john amy", 
"brad hailey john amy", "brad hailey", "brad hailey", "hailey amy", 
"hailey amy", "hailey john", "hailey john", "hailey john amy", 
"hailey john amy", "hailey", "hailey"), complete_team = c("adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
"adam, mike, brittany", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
"brad, hailey"), team = c("team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
"team1", "team1", "team1", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", 
"team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", 
"team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", 
"team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2"), trailhead_start = c("trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
"trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
"trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two"), total_hours = c(10L, 
7L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
7L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: somehow it is not clear for me what you want. And I think that is the most confusing how the data is presented.

Comment: team_components_at_departure  means - these were those who were actually running?

Comment: what does other_team_members_at_departure  mean actually and all_team_members_at_departure ? - so there are two dfifferent kind of trails. - so the sum of both trails are actually the entire trails' duration?

Comment: oof i was afraid of that, I will edit to try to be more clear. Yes; team_components_at_departure are those actually running in that row

Comment: If they are those actually running - two infos are totally useless: `team` and `complete_team`.

Comment: because we need only actually those who are actually running - they are the actual "team".

Comment: It is not completely useless, since we need to know all of the members of the team (`complete_team`) that need to finish for everyone to be done. We can't only look at the individual runners. `team` is redundant though.

Comment: in the process of editing the quesiton to make it more clear, thanks!

Comment: what does trail_one and trail_two mean? There are two trails? So when is a run completed for a combination of members? When trail one and trail two are both finished?

Comment: Because depending on that one has to count completely differently. I would put away the assumption - with different team members certain subgroups run differently, first. The data itself will show whether this is the case or not.

Comment: trail_one and trail_two are separate races. each row represents the completion of a race by whoever is in  `team_runners_at_departure` (I changed the names to help explain better). the length of time it took them to run the race is in `total_hours`. thanks!

Comment: but they are very different in this example - I thought one has to sum trail_one and trail_two to to get total race duration. If you split by all_team_mems_by_departure, you get dataframes where within each dataframe, there are no differences in all columns except that of trail and time.

Comment: So I would say trail_one and trail_two belong together and have to be summed up. To give the total race's run time.

Comment: team_components_at_departure and other_team_members_at_departure means who is running trail_one and who is running trail_two. -> and that exactly is that problem - that it was not clear to you how to count and what to do exactly.

Comment: So do first: `df <- as.data.frame(df);
dfs <- split(df, df$all_team_mems_at_departure);
times <- sapply(dfs, function(df) sum(df$total_hours))` - `times` then is the total race time for all_team_mems.

Comment: `min(times)` gives `6` which is  `names(times[times == 6])` 
[1] "adam mike fred gina"     "mike brittany fred gina" - so these are the groups which run fastest.

Comment: Thanks! I rewrote the question and I think it is a lot clearer now. The teams aren't running at the same time or anything. I  want to find what *combination* of runners is fastest - so what combination of `team_runners_at_departure` and `other_runners_at_departure` can get all of the people in `complete_team` finished the fastest? this will require simultaneously comparing multiple rows rather than finding 'the fastest' times

Comment: I think you complicate the task unnecessarily. Just find the fastest subgroup (those actually running). If you identified them, just take their complete_team.

Comment: But what if that is not the fastest way for the team to finish the race? It could easily be the case that they should run separately, or against other opponents.

Answer (score 0):

So given the current information, I tried this:
Create the data:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(team_components_at_departure = c("adam", "adam", 
                                                "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam", "adam, brittany", 
                                                "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", 
                                                "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, brittany", "adam, mike", 
                                                "adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike", 
                                                "adam, mike", "adam, mike", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                                "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                                "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                                "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", "brittany", 
                                                "brittany", "brittany", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", 
                                                "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", 
                                                "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", "mike, brittany", 
                                                "mike, brittany", "brad", "brad", "brad", "brad", "brad", "brad", 
                                                "brad", "brad", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                                "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                                "brad, hailey", "hailey", "hailey", "hailey", "hailey", "hailey", 
                                                "hailey", "hailey", "hailey"), 
               other_team_members_at_departure = c("fred", 
                                                   "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", "none", 
                                                   "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", 
                                                   "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", 
                                                   "none", "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", 
                                                   "gina", "none", "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", "fred, gina", 
                                                   "gina", "gina", "none", "none", "fred", "fred", "fred, gina", 
                                                   "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", "none", "fred", "fred", 
                                                   "fred, gina", "fred, gina", "gina", "gina", "none", "none", "amy", 
                                                   "amy", "john", "john", "john, amy", "john, amy", "none", "none", 
                                                   "amy", "amy", "john", "john", "john, amy", "john, amy", "none", 
                                                   "none", "amy", "amy", "john", "john", "john, amy", "john, amy", 
                                                   "none", "none"), 
               all_team_mems_at_departure = c("adam fred", 
                                              "adam fred", "adam fred gina", "adam fred gina", "adam gina", 
                                              "adam gina", "adam", "adam", "adam brittany fred", "adam brittany fred", 
                                              "adam brittany fred gina", "adam brittany fred gina", "adam brittany gina", 
                                              "adam brittany gina", "adam brittany", "adam brittany", "adam mike fred", 
                                              "adam mike fred", "adam mike fred gina", "adam mike fred gina", 
                                              "adam mike gina", "adam mike gina", "adam mike", "adam mike", 
                                              "adam mike brittany fred", "adam mike brittany fred", "adam mike brittany fred gina", 
                                              "adam mike brittany fred gina", "adam mike brittany gina", "adam mike brittany gina", 
                                              "adam mike brittany", "adam mike brittany", "brittany fred", 
                                              "brittany fred", "brittany fred gina", "brittany fred gina", 
                                              "brittany gina", "brittany gina", "brittany", "brittany", "mike fred", 
                                              "mike fred", "mike fred gina", "mike fred gina", "mike gina", 
                                              "mike gina", "mike", "mike", "mike brittany fred", "mike brittany fred", 
                                              "mike brittany fred gina", "mike brittany fred gina", "mike brittany gina", 
                                              "mike brittany gina", "mike brittany", "mike brittany", "brad amy", 
                                              "brad amy", "brad john", "brad john", "brad john amy", "brad john amy", 
                                              "brad", "brad", "brad hailey amy", "brad hailey amy", "brad hailey john", 
                                              "brad hailey john", "brad hailey john amy", "brad hailey john amy", 
                                              "brad hailey", "brad hailey", "hailey amy", "hailey amy", "hailey john", 
                                              "hailey john", "hailey john amy", "hailey john amy", "hailey", 
                                              "hailey"), 
               complete_team = c("adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", "adam, mike, brittany", 
                                 "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                 "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                 "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                 "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                 "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", 
                                 "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey", "brad, hailey"
               ), 
               team = c("team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", "team1", 
                        "team1", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", 
                        "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", 
                        "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2", 
                        "team2", "team2", "team2", "team2"), 
               trailhead = c("trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", 
                             "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two", 
                             "trail_one", "trail_two", "trail_one", "trail_two"), 
               total_hours = c(10L, 
                               7L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                               8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 
                               2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 
                               3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
                               5L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                               7L, 3L)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -80L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                    "data.frame"))
```

And using this data structure, calculate total race's time for each combination of members:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
dfs <- split(df, df$all_team_mems_at_departure)
times <- sapply(dfs, function(df) sum(df$total_hours))
```

In this example data you gave, `dfs` if you inspect it, depends of rows exactly identical except for `trailhead` which are always trail_one and trail_two and `total_hours`.
While total_hours are so different e.g. `7` and `1` that I assume, one has to sum them up to get the total trail/race's time.

And then use this info to find minimal time's groups:

```
names(times[times == min(times)])
## [1] "adam mike fred gina"     "mike brittany fred gina"
```

Comment: All the combinations of runners (`team_runners_at_departure` and `other_runners_at_departure`) are the same across the two races, but they are different races and have different `total_hours`. I need a solution that can generalize to many different races.

I want to find what combination of runners is fastest - so what combination of `team_runners_at_departure` and `other_runners_at_departure` can get all of the people in `complete_team` finished the fastest (minimize `total_hours`)? this will require simultaneously comparing multiple rows rather than finding 'the fastest' times. Thanks tho!

Comment: okay the toy dataset is just made up? It is an unlogical toy dataset - not making the actual problem clear.

Comment: what is the actual dataset? can you post is somewhere?

Comment: even if it is so that trail_one and trail_two are different trails, for this question to answer - it is best to sum them up. - it is same like building average over them. because in the `dfs` of toy dataset - I see no other combinations within the same `df`. If I would see them, I would know that this is the problem. But it is not present. if there would be other combinations within the sub-dfs, I would split the sub-dfs again. or better in the beginning split take them into account (split by multiple columns) - like

Comment: `split(df, c(df$all_runners_at_departure, df$team_runners_at_departure, df$other_runners_at_departure))`.